# Loading an .obj with JOGL

Tags: java, jogl, .obj

I have found may tutorials on loading an obj, but nothing on how to load it and use it with java, anyone have links to any useful tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

The closest that I could find were:

- [JOGL-ES Chapter 2 - Loading OBJ Models](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en___US304&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=JOGL-ES+loading+obj+models)
- [OBJ File Format](http://www.royriggs.com/obj.html)
- [OBJ Loader, Renderer Independent](http://www.pixelnerve.com/v/2009/02/06/another-obj-file-loader/)

Keep in mind that JOGL is a very low-level API.  Some of the higher-level APIs (JMonkeyEngine, and Java3D) have sophisticated APIs built in for handling this sort of thing.  With JOGL, you will be doing much of the work yourself.  Obviously, there are advantages and disadvantages to each approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not a tutorial, but how about some sample code?  Unfortunately it uses the "Fixed Function Pipeline" rather than using the new "do everything with shaders" approach, but I like to think the code is clear.

http://darksleep.com/oObjLoader/

Also, I should note that it does use VBOs and not direct rendering or display lists, so it is fairly efficient.

Comment: I downvote because your example doesn't use JOGL, the source code is on Github: https://github.com/seanrowens/oObjLoader There are numerous examples using JOGL as you can see in my reply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35072625/458157