# Render 3d .obj file to .png image

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

Is there at least some way to get a picture of a .obj model without displaying the model ? 
I have a lot of .obj models and I need to convert them to .png images.
I need only image without display anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading an .obj with JOGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775648/loading-an-obj-with-jogl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need libgdx for obj rendering. This can be done by either opengl, or some custom render libs.

Consider using [this library](https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/tree/0c1d955e4f86c25f31f97e4f4563313ddba0c104) written in c++ for obj rendering. Here's its [description in russian](http://habrahabr.ru/post/249139/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to do this in libgdx? I think you can also call blender via command line, let it render the scene and output to an image. Make a short bash script to do this for all .obj files in your folder.

If you do need to use libgdx, I think a good approach is to render to a framebuffer, then write its contents to a file.